# Unable to cast MS Graph Message as EventMessage

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We have a .NET Core application that checks for new calendar meeting requests through the Microsoft Graph and then parses the event information. This application has been working for the past year and recently (best guess is July 1st) stopped working. The following code uses the [MS Graph .NET Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) version 1.15.0 to request the Message and Event data as well as cast it as an EventMessage.

```
public async Task<(List<Event>, DateTimeOffset?)> GetCalendarEventsCreatedSince(DateTimeOffset? lastRetrievalDate)
{
    var lastRetrievalDateString = lastRetrievalDate.Value.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'", null as DateTimeFormatInfo);
    var eventMessages = await this._graphServiceClient.Me.Messages.Request()
        .Top(50)
        .Filter($"createdDateTime gt {lastRetrievalDateString} and microsoft.graph.eventMessage/meetingMessageType eq 'meetingRequest'")
        .Expand("microsoft.graph.eventMessage/event, attachments")
        .GetAsync();

    foreach (var eventMessage in eventMessages)
    {
        var calEvent = (eventMessage as EventMessage)?.Event;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The issue is `(eventMessage as EventMessage)` has started returning null and we cannot determine why. The fields specific to an `EventMessage` in v1.15 of the sdk are MeetingMessageType and Event, both of which are returned.

We have tried:

- Pulling the `Event` object from the `AdditionalData` property on the `eventMessage`. `calEvent` evaluates to null.

```
foreach (var eventMessage in eventMessages)
{
    if (eventMessage.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("event", out var eventData))
    {
        var calEvent = eventData as Event;
    }
}
```

- Requesting the specific message data by id. `calEvent` evaluates to null.

```
foreach (var eventMessage in eventMessages)
{
    var individualMessage = await this._graphServiceClient.Me.Messages[eventMessage.Id].Request().GetAsync();
    var calEvent = individualMessage as EventMessage;
}
```

- Upgrading the MS Graph .NET Library to version 3.8.0 (latest). Same issue. EventMessage has more fields in the class. The only field not included in the response from the graph is EventMessage.Location.
- Reviewed the [MS Graph API Changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), but did not see anything specific to Message, EventMessage, or Event. There are some [known issues with query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#query-parameter-limitations), but we're not seeing any missing data.

We appreciate any thoughts or ideas--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are unsure exactly why this is the case but here's our solution after upgrading to v3.8.0 of the Microsoft Graph .NET Library.

The "event" property exists on `eventMessage.AdditionalData`, but the value is of type `Newton.Json.JObject`. We convert the JObject into an Event and then we can continue.

```
foreach (var eventMessage in eventMessages)
{
    if (eventMessage.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("event", out var eventData))
    {
        var calEvent = (eventData as JObject)?.ToObject<Event>();
        ...
    }
}
```

If anyone has any clue as to why this solution is suddenly necessary, please let us know.